# Mailgun PHP API changed on 1/23/2018 SSL Certificate Error not resolved with new cacert.pem file

Tags: php, api, ssl, certificate, mailgun

My PHP Mailgun interface had been working for 2 years until yesterday 1/23/2018 at about 12 noon central time.

Now all calls to the Mailgun API are returning the SSL certificate problem

Exception 0 [curl] 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate [url] https://api.mailgun.net/v2/

Curl also returns the same problem at the command line when attempting to access the mailgun API.

We have downloaded and installed the latest cacert.pem file from 
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and includeded the path to this file in the php.ini file parameter curl.cainfo = /path/to/cacert.pem  and the openssl.cafile = /path/to/cacert.pem

We have restarted our application and rebooted our server but the problem is not fixed.

Is anyone else having the same problem with the PHP Mailgun API  ?
Is there a way to disable the SSL certificate check through the Mailgun API ?

Comment: Run `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect api.mailgun.net:443` from the command line, hit `Ctrl+D` to close the connection, and copy/paste the result into your question.

Comment: Same issue for me... My server doesn't currently have SSL. Is SSL now required in order to curl to mailgun? I tried the other answers and nothing's working...

Comment: Nevermind - I got it working by using the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option (`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'path/to/cacert.pem');`) to point to my local cacert.pem. Since I'm on shared hosting, using guzzle 6 and running it through a laravel command, the other answers involving editing php.ini, replacing the file in guzzle or updating the server's ca certs were out of the question for me...

Answer (score 9):

The SSL Certificate problem with the PHP Mailgun API was resolved by copying the  latest cacert.pem file to the following directory :
..PHP\v5.6\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Resources\

Apparently the PHP MailGun API  uses this directory for the certificates when calling the guzzle and curl interfaces.
Changing the PHP.ini file  parameter  curl.cainfo = "/path/to/cacert.pem"  is not sufficient to resolve this problem.

Comment: Thanks @stever, you can get the latest certs from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)

Comment: Thanks - this was driving a friend of mine nuts

Comment: Thanks - this was driving me nuts too.

Answer (score 0):

Do we really need to install guzzle to fix this issue? I encounter same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just came to SO myself to post a resolution my team and I found on this issue as well.  As we have a Laravel 4.2 website running Guzzle 4.x for Mailgun mail delivery, all emails ceased functioning as Steve said on 1/23 around Noon.

For us, we simply had to update the cacert.pem found in the /vendor/guzzlehttp directory that the package uses and it came back online.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm updating php / curl on my dead ass old production server resolved this problem.

Actually, this should be sufficent:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem... you just need to change de "pem" file inside:
guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Resources/

You need to get de cacert.pem here... the last version:
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

And after, just change in your folder.

Answer (score -3):

Actually, it's not a bug; it's for security reasons. To make it work, change

```
$sslEnabled = true
```

to

```
$sslEnabled = false
```

You can read extra details at [this github issue](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/issues/174#issuecomment-368864372).